# Castle Windsor ILazyComponentLoader Recursion

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

Is the ILazyComponentLoader for Castle Windsor recursive? That is, if the lazy loaded component has a dependency, will Windsor try to lazy load that dependency as well?

If not, can someone suggest a way of doing this?

If so...I can't seem to make this work...I keep getting an error after lazy loading the first component that a dependency cannot be satisfied...any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You have to draw a line somewhere. `ILazyComponentLoaders` in general are meant to be used in very, very, very rare cases, when you seriously genuinely have absolutely no way whatsoever to pre-register the components.

I think the chance of having a `ILazyComponentLoader` that itself has dependencies meeting aforementioned criteria are so slim that you are more likely to die being hit by a meteorite.

In other words - you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I actually didn't mean that the ILazyComponentLoader has a dependency, but rather that the component the ILazyComponentLoader is requested to load has a dependency itself that must be lazy loaded...which doesn't seem to be working for me...?

Comment: well you explicitly said: __That is, if the lazy loaded component has a dependency, will Windsor try to lazy load that dependency as well?__ Perhaps you should rephrase the question. The way you're describing it now I can't say from the top of my head why it wouldn't work... unless I'm not seeing something it seems it should. Let me have a look. What version are you using?

Comment: _That is, if the lazy **loaded** component has a dependency. Not **loader** component_

Comment: OK, I just tested and it works. So either you're doing something wrong or your scenario is more complicated than you describe. Either way, I think it's time for a failing test case.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong. I'm trying to register another component manually inside the ILazyComponentLoader.Load method. If I register it normally (not within the context of the Load method), the Lazy Resolution happens fine later.